# Finding maximum of this function.

Tags: calculus, optimization

> $\mathbf{Question}$ Find the maximum of $F(a,b,c,d)=\frac{5}{4}(c-a)^{2}+\frac{3}{4}(d-b)^{2}+2\sqrt{3}(c-a)(d-b)$ when 
>   $(a,b,c,d)\in\mathbf{R}^{4},a^{2}+b^{2}\leq 4$ and $c^{2}+d^{2}\leq 4$.

I tried to find critical points of $F(a,b,c,d)$ within the interior and I found that $F$ is 0 at the critical points within the interior. And then I tried to use Lagrange multiplier at the boundary. But the calculations of Lagrange multiplier got quite cumbersome and so after a while I gave up and tried to ask Wolframalpha to solve this.

But when I plugged in the problem at http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=maximize, Wolframalpha couldn't find the maximum. But because the domain is compact, maximum should exist.

I'd like to ask if some program could easily solve this problem because the target function and the constraints are given by rather simple polynomials.

Comment: what do we know about the variables?

Comment: the variables are real numbers, I just edited the question.

Comment: you must compute the partial derivatives

Comment: @ Dr. Sonnhard Graubner: I did. But what I'd like to ask is if some program can solve this easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A= \begin{bmatrix} 5 & 4 \sqrt{3} \\ 4 \sqrt{3} & 3 \end{bmatrix}$,
and note that the problem is
$\max \{ {1 \over 4} \langle (c-a,d-b)^T , A(c-a,d-b)^T \rangle | \, \|(a,b)^T\| \le 2, \|(c,d)^T\| \le 2\}$.

To simplify slightly, let $y_1 = a, x_1 = c-a$, $y_2 = b, x_2 = d-b$, then
the problem becomes
$\max \{ {1 \over 4} \langle x , Ax \rangle | \, \|y\| \le 2, \|x+y\| \le 2\}$.

The matrix $A$ is symmetric and has eigenvalues $-3,11$, and the constraints
are rotation invariant, so we can write the problem as
$\max \{ {1 \over 4} (11x_1^2 - 3 x_2^2) | \, \|y\| \le 2, \|x+y\| \le 2\}$.

It is not difficult to show that 
$\{ x | \ \|y\| \le 2, \|x+y\| \le 2\} = \{ x | \|x \| \le 4 \}$, hence
the problem reduces to
$\max \{ {1 \over 4} (11x_1^2 - 3 x_2^2) | \, \|x\| \le 4 \}$, which
has a value ${1 \over 4} 11 \cdot 4^2 = 44$